# ListView Observable Collection Will Not Show Members

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Cannot get my listview to display data.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListView Name="lstDetectedComputers" 
                  MinWidth="200" 
                  DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ComputersList}" DisplayMemberPath="ComputerName">
        </ListView>
        <DataGrid x:Name="ViewNetworkCardInformation" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkCardInformation}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private ObservableCollection<Object> _ComputersList;
public ObservableCollection<Object> ComputersList
{
    get 
    { 
        return _ComputersList;
    }

    set 
    {
        _ComputersList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ComputersList");
    }
}

private DataTable _NetworkCardInformation;
public DataTable NetworkCardInformation
{
    get 
    { 
        return _NetworkCardInformation; 
    }

    set 
    { 
        _NetworkCardInformation = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("NetworkCardInformation"); 
    }
}
```

Strange thing is that NetworkCardInformation shows in my datagrid so this indicates that the datacontext is working as expected.

now im under the impression with a ObservableCollection i do not need a INotifyPropertyChange, if this is wrong please advised.

i have also tried just ItemsSource="{Binding ComputersList}"

I have put a break point into the code to ensure that the observable collection has data, and it is there .

- ComputersList   Count = 2   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection
- [0] {AdminUltimate.Model.NetworkModel.ComputerNode} object {AdminUltimate.Model.NetworkModel.ComputerNode}
      ComputerName    "ASUS-PC"   string

Could someone please assist.
Thank you

Comment: Wrong impression.  ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged (not INotifyPropertyChanged).  OC notifies inserts and deletes - not changes to existing items.

Comment: Try to declare `ComputersList` property as `ObservableCollection<ComputerNode>` instead of `ObservableCollection<Object>`

Comment: Agree with har07.  NotifyPropertyChanged("ComputersList"); does not belong there.   ComputerNode needs a  NotifyPropertyChanged("ComputerName");

Comment: @Blam - `ObservableCollection` implements both `INPC` and `INCC`. However, your other assertion is true that any property change in underlying object won't be refreshed on GUI, for that object should implement `INPC`.

Comment: @RohitVats I stand corrected

Answer (score 1):

You have set `DisplayMemberPath` as `ComputerName` but `Object` doesn't have any such property so it shows nothing on view.

This can be validated by removing `DisplayMemberPath`, you will see fully qualified class name of your object since `ToString()` gets called on your object if no ItemTemplate and DisplayMemberPath is set on ListBox.

So, solution would be to **change `ObservableCollection<Object>` to type of more concrete object containing property `ComputerName` i.e. `ObservableCollection<ComputerNode>`**.

Comment: You know they are looking for moderators.  I think you would be a good moderator if you have the time.  Never mind you don't have the required badges.

Comment: Thanks Blam. Yeah I just saw about it. But working professionally and taking out time daily will be bit tedious. I love checking out SO on and off but yeah like you said I am running out of badges. So, may be will give it a shot next time. :)